prisma : how can i get transactions of a specifc user?
I have the following schema :
model User {
  id            String       @id @default(uuid())
  email         String       @unique
  createdAt     DateTime     @default(now())
  budgets       Budget[]
}

model Budget {
  id           String       @id @default(uuid())
  name         String
  amount       Float
  userId       String
  user         User         @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  emoji        String?   
  transactions Transaction[]
  createdAt    DateTime     @default(now())
}

model Transaction {
  id           String     @id @default(uuid())
  description  String
  amount       Float
  budgetId     String?
  budget       Budget?    @relation(fields: [budgetId], references: [id])
  emoji        String?  
  createdAt    DateTime   @default(now())
}

My goal is to make a query that displays ONLY the transactions that the user created when he logged in to the web app, and NOT the transactions created by other users. How can I do that? (I am new to prisma)

Have you read https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/queries/relation-queries

What have you tried so far?

const userId = 'userId'; // ID of the user you want to filter

const transactions = await prisma.transaction.findMany({
  where: {
    budget: {
      userId: userId,
    },
  },
});


Uses findMany on Transaction to fetch multiple transactions.
Filters with where to only get transactions where the budget is associated with the specified userId.

